# Huawei P20 lite not recognizing external keyboard

Tags: huawei, external-keyboard, huawei-p20

I got this keyboard from China that has holder for a phone, but has USB-micro cable.
My phone (Huawei P20 lite) has USB-C, but that's not an issue, since I got usb-micro to usb-C converter. I tried to connect the keyboard through 3 different usb-micro to usb-C converters, but in any case the keyboard didn't work.

A friend of mine tried on Samsung S5(usb-micro) and S9(usb-c) aswell, using another 3 different usb-micro to usb-c converters. It worked well on S5 (usb-micro) but didn't work anyhow on S9(usb-c).

Tried aswell as downloading Swift keyboard (just in case it has any features) and 
go to Settings > Language > Default keyboard > Input settings, but there was no options whatsoever.

I can't figure out what could possibly go wrong, while it's totally functionally working on all usb-micro devices and never on usb-c.

How to solve this problem, what to do about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same with external keyboard, camera. It looks like the USB C Port does not support the extarnal interfaces, cannot supply. I have a small camera that lights automatically if connected to Samsung, but not on Huawei. Solution is iteressting for me also.

Have fun.